# Where/when to insert credentials in angular 2 bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrapping, angular2-services

Hi I've a basic question on Angular bootstrap process.

I'm working on a simple authentication sdk for angular 2 which lets people connect to a backend service using Url, appID and appSecret as credentials.

These credentials should be entered manually somewhere (on the client-side) and should be accessible on bootstrap.

The goal is to ensure that http requests can be performed with these credentials as headers at any given time (e.g. on bootstrap).

So far my idea is to use a service in the root component like

```
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private init:SDKInit, private service2, 3,...){
        this.init.set(credentials...)
    }
}
```

I know that services need to be injected before they can launch but in the above case I pretty sure that if service 2 wants to perform an http, the credentials won't be ready yet..
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to have credentials that the user needs to insert using the app, but they must be available before the app bootstraps?

Comment: Why do you need them before bootstraping ? You could show a login page first then move on.

Comment: the credentials are not for the end user so it's not username and password. It's for the developer who wishes to use the backend service of ours.